# Why does the Boost Graph Library invalidate all iterators when removing a vertex?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

In the [Boost Graph Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) documentation it [says](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) that when you remove a vertex from a graph (when its vertices are stored in a vector at least), all iterators (and descriptors) are invalidated.

This surprised me, as it seems not be semantically necessary to do so.

Is there a way to make `adjacency_list` work in a way that doesn't aggressively invalidate iterators in such a case? Can't I somehow just 'invalidate' the vertex and garbage-collect it at some convenient time?

Comment: You do know that happens because of the underlying vector? If you add or remove elements from a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) then all iterators might be invalidated.

Comment: Frankly, your question reads like an unconstructive rant. I can edit it for you, but perhaps you want to do so.

Comment: @sehe: Better? If not, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the underlying container semantics: [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

It's also clearly a trade-off: you get O(1) vertex indexing for free.

If you want something else, use a different container selector (e.g. `listS` ) for the vertex container.

> Isn't it (generally) better to just 'invalidate' the vertex in the vector and garbage-collect it when the next resize is necessary?

It's indeed a common pattern to mark vertices as deleted. `boost::filtered_graph<>` is a handy adaptor for such cases.

Comment: 1. A different design choice than just passing the removal on to the container would have spared me the trade-off. 2.  I take it a `filtered_graph` adds a 'deleted' boolean property to each vertex (or edge, or both), and overrides the removal operations?

Comment: It would have gotten you another, equally arbitrary, trade-off, obviously. Filtered graph just filters. No overriding done. You "logically" delete vertices by adding them to the filtered set. I (and some others) have answers on SO demonstrating this.